# IntelliJ IDEA test module in different project

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, junit

How can I make (if it's possible) different project in IntelliJ IDEA that would contain test classes for my "main" project. It's important to be in separated project because client uses remote build server (Jenkins) and I don't want tests to be built with other code. Is it possible to do it, something like this:

```
MainProject
  assets
  bin
  src
    com
      package1
         Class1.java
      package2
         Class2.java

MainProjectTests
  src
    com
      package1
        Class1Test.java
```

Comment: No, I don't. Should I?

Comment: If you use Maven, you can skip unit tests by adding -DskipTests to the build command, it's also available with Gradle.

Comment: Have you tried just setting up two modules/projects as you've outlined? If so what problems are you seeing?

Comment: Yes, I tried to create new module, but it makes new package inside src folder of MainProject and it's called test.com.package1 for example.

Comment: Import this project into Intellij and you get the idea... https://github.com/openshift/kitchensink-example/blob/master/pom.xml